# How to upload only one module to jitpack

Tags: maven, jitpack

I am making a java project with maven that has this structure:

```
parent
 |- api (depends on common)
 |- common
 |- plugin (depends on api and common)
```

People should only be able to use the classes inside the "api" module, not common or plugin.

I have read the docs and all I should do is put the repository in the parent pom and then use the module's artifactId. However, this would upload the whole project and I don't want people to be able to use classes other than the ones in the api module.

Is it possible to just upload the api module? Or it isn't and I just have to upload everything?

In summary, I want to know if it's possible to upload ONLY the api submodule.